# Linear algebra problem phrasing

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I do know how to solve a system of equations with an augmented matrix. But I'm not sure if that's what I have to do here. Can somebody help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hckyT.jpg)

Comment: To maximize the chance of receiving help, you should clarify what you are really asking, add a reference to the textbook you are posting a picture of, and show what you have attempted so far!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linear system
$$
Ax=b
$$
where $A=(a_{ij})$ is a square matrix and $b=(b_{i})$ is a vector
of appropriate dimensions. More explicitly, we can write this as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_{1}\\
\vdots\\
x_{n}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b_{1}\\
\vdots\\
b_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
or equivalently as the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
a_{11}x_{1}+\cdots+a_{1n}x_{n}=b_{1}\\
\vdots\\
a_{n1}x_{1}+\cdots+a_{nn}x_{n}=b_{n}.
\end{cases}
$$

Row reduction is a procedure in which various operations are performed on the linear system to arrive at an (equivalent) upper triangular linear system of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}^{\prime} & \cdots & a_{1n}^{\prime}\\
 & \ddots & \vdots\\
 &  & a_{nn}^{\prime}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_{1}\\
\vdots\\
x_{n}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b_{1}^{\prime}\\
\vdots\\
b_{n}^{\prime}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Note that row reduction does not modify the vector $x$. Therefore,
it is reasonable to represent row reduction in the following way:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} & b_{1}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn} & b_{n}
\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{\text{row reduce}}\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}^{\prime} & \cdots & a_{1n}^{\prime} & b_{1}^{\prime}\\
 & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 &  & a_{nn}^{\prime} & b_{n}^{\prime}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The matrices above are referred to as "augmented" in that they
also carry information from the right-hand sides $b$ and $b^{\prime}$
of the linear systems above.

The question on your assignment is testing your knowledge of these
concepts, and for example, asking you to go back and forth between
the notations.